# Sass can't @use members from partials

Tags: sass

I am trying to `@use` members from other partials, just like it is shown in Sass' docs, but I am getting an error when compiling it.

Example is:

```
// _base.scss
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

```
//styles.scss
@use 'base';

.inverse {
  background-color: base.$primary-color;
  color: white;
}
```

Error I am getting:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...und-color: base": expected ";", was ".$primary-color;"
        on line 4 of styles.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

I really wonder what I am doing wrong, because I have emulated exactly what is shown in the docs. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by reinstalling Sass with npm. Problem was caused by installing Sass using the `brew install sass/sass/sass` command.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by using `@import` instead of `@use`

Comment: You can resolve the issue by installing the Dart version, by installing it via npm for example.